# the mistakes that Visual Studio Code shows, are they real?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

When developing a flutter app using Visual Studio Code

App freezing errors appear on the phone

And the error appears in a new tab, like the one shown in the picture below

[image]

Note that these errors do not appear in the rest of the editors

Like android studio and intellij

Are they mistakes that I should fix or not

thank you

Comment: you should take a look into the error,as you can see it clearly state incorrect use of Expanded widget. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Comment: Your Screenshot shows Visual Studio **Code**. I changed the tags and headline for you. Visual Studio without the word Code is a completely different product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you debug the flutter code it automatically breakpoint whenever there is some error or chance of future breakdown. If you run the application it will not show error. In visual studio try to run code not debug code. Even if you debug in android studio it will show you those screen.

Answer (score 1):

The error is true

You have put an `Expanded` (inside a `Padding`) in a `Column`, which means the `Expanded` widget will try to take as much space as possible in a `Column` widget which will have the height of its childs, making the `Column`’s height infinite. Try nesting the `Column` in a `SizedBox` or `Container` with height and width